# How to Output Subarray?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a problem to output subarray values properly. I use **Codestar Framework** to create options.

Here is my options code:

```
array(
    'id'     => 'rows',
    'type'   => 'group',
    'title'  => 'Rows',
    'accordion_title_auto'   => false,
    'accordion_title_prefix' => 'Row',
    'accordion_title_number' => true,
    'fields'  => array(
        array(
            'id'     => 'columns',
            'type'   => 'group',
            'title'  => 'Columns',
            'accordion_title_auto'   => false,
            'accordion_title_prefix' => 'Column',
            'accordion_title_number' => true,
            'fields'    => array(
                array(
                    'id'      => 'column-color',
                    'type'    => 'select',
                    'title'   => 'Color',
                    'options' => array(
                        'red'    => 'Red',
                        'blue'   => 'Blue',
                        'green'  => 'Green',
                    ),
                ),
                array(
                    'id'       => 'column-price',
                    'type'     => 'select',
                    'title'    => 'Price',
                    'options'  => array(
                        'low'     => 'Low',
                        'medium'  => ' Medium',
                        'high'    => ' High',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),

),
```

I have done it so far and it works. But how to output color and price? I can't figure it out how to do it correctly.

```
$rows = $options['rows'];
foreach ( $rows as $id => $name ) { 
   echo '<div class="row-'. $id .'">';
   foreach ( $name['columns'] as $id_col => $name_col ) {
      echo '<div class="column-'. $id_col .'">';
      echo'...';
      echo '</div>';
   }
   echo '</div>';
}

<div class="row-0">
   <div class="column-0">...</div>
   <div class="column-1">...</div>
</div>
<div class="row-1">
   <div class="column-0">...</div>
</div>
```

I want to output look like this:

```
<div class="row-0">
    <div class="column-0 color-red">
        Price - Low
    </div>
    <div class="column-1 color-green">
        Price - Medium
    </div>
</div>

</div>
<div class="row-1">
    <div class="column-0 color-blue">
        Price - High
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me with this? I will be very grateful, thanks

**UPDATE**

This code displays all values:

```
foreach ( $rows as $id => $name ) {
    echo '<div class="row-'. $id .'">';
    foreach ( $name['columns'] as $id_col => $name_col ) {
        echo '<div class="column-'. $id_col .' color-'. $name_col['column-color'] .'">';
            echo $name_col['column-content'];
        echo '</div>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

I just don't know how to make 'column-content' output not an option key string but a key value/label

Comment: The word you looking for is `recursion`. This article will probably help you https://thisinterestsme.com/php-using-recursion-print-values-multidimensional-array/

Comment: Are you sure that you want to continue working with such a strange array structure? Why not refactor your application to use better designed data structures?

Comment: @Avigo Is there any rule to match `low price` with `red color`? The data seems incorrect.

Comment: @NicoHaase, are you saying that the framework I use doesn't have a quite clear structure and it is better to use another one?

Comment: I've never heard of the framework you are using, but if you struggle to use the provided data, a change might make sense

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
$options = array(
    'id'     => 'rows',
    'type'   => 'group',
    'title'  => 'Rows',
    'accordion_title_auto'   => false,
    'accordion_title_prefix' => 'Row',
    'accordion_title_number' => true,
    'fields'  => array(
        array(
            'id'     => 'columns',
            'type'   => 'group',
            'title'  => 'Columns',
            'accordion_title_auto'   => false,
            'accordion_title_prefix' => 'Column',
            'accordion_title_number' => true,
            'fields'    => array(
                array(
                    'id'      => 'column-color',
                    'type'    => 'select',
                    'title'   => 'Color',
                    'options' => array(
                        'red'    => 'Red',
                        'blue'   => 'Blue',
                        'green'  => 'Green',
                    ),
                ),
                array(
                    'id'       => 'column-price',
                    'type'     => 'select',
                    'title'    => 'Price',
                    'options'  => array(
                        'low'     => 'Low',
                        'medium'  => ' Medium',
                        'high'    => ' High',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);


$fields = $options['fields'];


    print_r( $fields );


foreach ( $fields as $key => $field ) {

    $color_options = $field['fields'][0]['options'];

    $price_options = $field['fields'][1]['options'];

    print_r( $price_options );  
}
```

which will generate something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => columns
            [type] => group
            [title] => Columns
            [accordion_title_auto] => 
            [accordion_title_prefix] => Column
            [accordion_title_number] => 1
            [fields] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => column-color
                            [type] => select
                            [title] => Color
                            [options] => Array
                                (
                                    [red] => Red
                                    [blue] => Blue
                                    [green] => Green
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => column-price
                            [type] => select
                            [title] => Price
                            [options] => Array
                                (
                                    [low] => Low
                                    [medium] =>  Medium
                                    [high] =>  High
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
Array
(
    [low] => Low
    [medium] =>  Medium
    [high] =>  High
)
```

Comment: What have you changed, and what makes you think that this solves the problem? Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Thanks for answer. print_r( $fields ); generate:
`
Array ( [0] => Array ( [columns] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [column-color] => red [column-price] => low ) [1] => Array ( [column-color] => green [column-price] => medium ) ) ) [1] => Array ( [columns] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [column-color] => blue [column-price] => high ) ) ) )
`

Comment: @Avigo Your generated array structure and question array structure is different? Is the array structure in the question correct?

Comment: @GarvitShrestha I use that array structure to generate option fields in admin options.